# How can I make a plain text paste in a contentEditable span without breaking undo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, contenteditable

Oddly specific question, but I have a solution already to paste plain text in a `<span contentEditable="true">` by using a hidden `textarea`, which seems to work really well, except that it breaks the browser's undo feature. Right off the bat I'm not worried about a cross-browser solution; I only care about Chrome. My approach looks roughly like this:

```
$('.editable').live('paste', function()
{
    var $this = $(this);

    //more code here to remember caret position, etc

    $('#clipboard').val('').focus(); //put the focus in the hidden textarea so that, when the paste actually occurs, it's auto-sanitized by the textarea

    setTimeout(function() //then this will be executed immediately after the paste actually occurs
    {
        $this.focus();
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', true, $('#clipboard').val());
    });
});
```

So this works -- I can paste anything and it's reduced to plain text before going into the my `contentEditable` field -- but if I try to undo after pasting:

- First undo undoes the paste.
- Second undo tries to undo the changes to `#clipboard`, moving the focus away from my `contentEditable`.

I've tried everything I can think of to make the browser not try to undo the changes to `#clipboard` -- toggling `display:none` when it's not actively in use, toggling `readonly` and `disabled` state, destroying it at the end of and recreating it at the beginning of the event above, various other hacks -- but nothing seems to work.

Is this a terrible approach to sanitization? This is the first thing I've managed to really get working -- trying to clean up the markup after the paste occurs didn't work, as there are some things (entire HTML documents) which, when pasted, crash the browser, which I'd like to avoid.

Is there any way to make the `#clipboard` not undoable, or any other suggestions of how to get this working?

### Edit

I managed to improve things a little bit by adding the line

```
$('#clipboard').val('');
```

Right after the `execCommand` line. This seems to neutralize undo completely: the caret no longer leaves the `contentEditable` field, but nothing gets undone at all. A bit of an improvement, but I'm still searching for a proper solution.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Since you're already using jQuery, why not just use a plugin like [markItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) or [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/jquery_plugin.php)?

Comment: @Matt - neither of those do what I'm asking. markItUp! uses a textarea -- nothing `contentEditable` there -- and TinyMCE allows pasting all kinds of markup. I'm not trying to make a rich text editor -- just the opposite, in fact. I'm trying to make a plain text `contentEditable` element. Just use a `textarea`, right? Would love to, but I need the content to wrap around other elements in the page.

Comment: "markItUp! uses a textarea" — erm... It is much simpler to change it, than writing own from scratch, isn't it?

Comment: @kirilloid: Not really. The mechanisms for dealing with selections and updating content are so completely different in `<textareas>` and `contenteditable` elements that switching between the two would require a complete rewrite.

Comment: Sounds to me like you might have to create your own undo mechanism.

Comment: @kirilloid - Rewriting markItUp! to not use `textarea` wouldn't help anything, even if it were feasible -- like I said, I'm not trying to create a rich text editor. Just trying to sanitize paste.

Comment: @Tim - I have no problem creating my own undo, but is there any way to disable the built in browser undo? Returning false on the keydown event would only work for, well, the keydown event. Doesn't seem to be any undo event to cancel in Chrome (although there are copy/paste events).

Comment: @Ian: There is no undo event, sadly. No browser allows you any access to the undo stack beyond `document.execCommand("undo")` and `document.execCommand("redo")`, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: WHATWG now has an UndoManager spec in the works: http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/undomanager/raw-file/tip/undomanager.html. I suspect it will be some time before it is usable in browsers though.

Comment: Small update: the 'live' method was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, use "on()" method instead for later versions.

Answer (score 1):

CodeMirror 1 does this by stripping away formatting after text is pasted. CodeMirror 2 does this by actually having an invisible textarea handle everything, and render the text and cursor manually.

CodeMirror's website describes how it works in more detail: http://codemirror.net/internals.html

Beyond that, there's always the CodeMirror source code. You can decide for yourself whether CodeMirror 1 or CodeMirror 2's approach is more suitable for your purposes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you try that?

```
setTimeout(function() //then this will be executed immediately after the paste actually occurs
{
    $this.focus();
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', true, $('#clipboard').val());
    var t = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.execCommand("undo");
    document.body.innerHTML = t;
});
```

I think it can help.
But I think you must use event object. Unfortunately there may be a problem cuz security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

In onpaste:

1. Store the current selection.

   ```
   var sel = window.getSelection();
   var range  = selObj.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange;
   // Store the range object somewhere.
   ```
2. Modify the selection object to point to your hidden textarea.
3. Set a timeout with a delay of 0 (occurs immediately after paste).
4. In the timeout function, grab the data from the hidden textarea, then:

   ```
   var sel = window.getSelection();
   sel.removeAllRanges();
   var range = // restore the range object from before.
   sel.addRange(range);

   document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, /* contents of your textarea here */);
   ```

Now if you wanted to do this for actual HTML content, you'd be in a world of hurt....

Comment: Typo: `cloneRange()`, not `cloneRange`. Also, this doesn't work in all browsers (can't remember the specifics) in the `paste` event: in some browsers it's just too late to redirect the paste once the paste event has fired. You can do it reliably for key events though (Ctrl-V etc.). Another problem is that the "InsertHTML" command doesn't work in IE (although you can use the `pasteHTML()` method of the selection TextRange instead). Finally, you can get pasted HTML by redirecting the paste to another contenteditable element and extracting its `innerHTML`.

Comment: Also, after looking at the question I suspect this technique is precisely what the OP is already doing.

Answer (score -2):

Insert a `<pre contenteditable="true">...</pre>`.  As I recall that's exactly what I understand you want.  (Unfortunately I'm not yet allowed to join everyone in the comments, but I suppose this is an attempt to answer anyway.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't make any difference. Can still paste whatever I want into the `<pre>` block and it appears just like the `<span>`.